# Rails app submitting 'post' request to a custom 'get' route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this button in my app, which is located in the views/deals/mgmt.htm.erb file:

```
<%= button_to "Deals", deals_mgmt_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

Here are my 'deals' routes specified in my routes file:

```
resources :deals
get "deals/mgmt"
```

When I run 'rake routes', here's the route as I specified:

```
deals_mgmt GET    /deals/mgmt(.:format)                    deals#mgmt
```

When I click the button, I get this routing error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/deals/mgmt"
```

Why is my rails trying to submit a post request here? I'm thoroughly confused. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The helper `button_to` creates a form, and forms submits `POST` requests to the server.
Inspect the page and you will see the form.
You should use a `link_to`, for a request using `GET`.

Comment: Can't accept for another 7 mins, but you're right. Didn't know that about button_to. Incidentally, I discovered you can pass a get request by doing something like: `<%= button_to 'something', some_path, {:method => get} %>`. Probably better to just use link_to though unless for good reason I suppose. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this: 

<%= button_to 'deals', deals_management_path, {:method => get} %>

Else
it's better to Go with link_to as by default it send get request to Server.

<%= link_to 'deals', deals_management_path %>
```

Comment: Yeah, just mentioned this earlier in my comment above. Agree that it's probably better to use link_to.